# Vue.JS - Both 'history' and 'abstract' router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, router

I am creating a VueJS app in which the user fills out a 5-step form.

These steps are routed to `/step-1` through `/step-5` in the Vue Router. However, I would like the site to return to the index page (`/`) when refreshing the page.

I could use `abstract` mode for this – but the result page is generated from the following url: `/result/:userid` in which I need the state to be `history` in order to be able to get the userid from the URL (and then do a post request to the server).

I also want this URL to be accessible even after finishing the form, so abstract here is not an option unfortunately.

So – is it possible to use both modes? Refresh the page to `index.html` when refreshing the form-pages, but then use `history` mode to render the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this. It is either **history** or **abstract** but not both. Having said this, there are a couple of things you can do.

#### Approach 1: Use `history` mode with steps as query params

So instead of having routes like `/step-1` or `/step-2`, use then as part of query params. So you will have routes like:

- Index route: `example.com/?step=1`, `example.com/?step=2`
- Result route: `example.com/result/:userId`

#### Approach 2: Use `abstract` mode with higher order component

Here, you will have a router with abstract but it will only serve as a state router and won't help with any browser URL manipulation.

Build a higher order component like `AppComponent` where you will have your own regular expressions to determine the route. It would look like:

```
// Should match route /result/:userId
const IS_RESULT = new RegExp('/result/(\\d+)$');

// User RegExp groups
const IS_STEP = new RegExp('/step-(\\d+)$');

export default class AppComponent extends Vue {

    // Use Vue.js created hook
    created() {
        const path = window.location.pathname;

        // Top level routing of the application
        if (IS_STEP.test(path)) {
            // Do something. You are in step-1/step-2/etc.
        } if (IS_RESULT.test(path)) {
            // Do something. You are in /result/:userId

            // Get userId
            const groups = IS_RESULT.exec(path);
            const userId = groups[1];
        } else {
            // Goto Error page
            throw new Error('Unknown route');
        }
    }

}
```

#### Approach 3: Use Multi-page SPA

Here, you will create two single page application. The first app will have routes `/step-1`, `/step-2`, etc. You will use **abstract** mode for this. The second application will have `/result/:userId` route with **history** mode.

In this architecture, when a user is on `step-5`, instead of pushing a new state to the router, you will use HTML5 history API to change the router and then cause a forced page refresh. Also, there are other ways you achieve this.

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for. I will have to go for the Query params option for this specific project.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have a redirect in native javascript where you call it window.location.href('yourHomePage.com') and it will do a full refresh.